# How can we implement Single sign on using C# WEB API (Without MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, webapi

The idea is to implement Single-sign on using the given technical stack (ASP.NET CORE WEB API, IdentityServer4, ReactJS - Front end)

ASP.NET Core Identity together with IdentityServer4 offers an extensions for Single-Sign-On (Google, Microsoft ect.) for MVC framework. However, a proper guidance is not given for a WEB API scenario.

Please provide me an example or a tutorial, which I can follow in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

*** Update ***

Would be great if an example is given for the flow of events on this scenario, as to how should the communication happen between the Front end application and the backend.

Comment: check this [article](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/identityserver4-in-aspnet-core/)

Comment: @CodingMytra - Thanks for the comment. However, this doesn't have any reference to the question I have asked.

Comment: then you have not checked the article properly. search for "Securing an ASP.NET Core WebAPI with IdentityServer4" in same article. there you have it.

Comment: In the said section, it doesn't contain, how to add single sign-on to the flow, in a non-mvc scenario.

Comment: I think you got some wrong understanding of Singlesign on. in the webapi you only configure from where token validation should happen. that's it. rest of the part should be done in your frontend for redirecting the call to identifyserver4 for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response @CodingMytra. Pls do share an example of the said scenario. That is exactly what I want to understand the flow of the execution.

Comment: here is another [article](https://code-maze.com/angular-oauth2-oidc-configuration-identityserver4/) it has nice workflow diagram. which talks about the workflow and integration of angular and identityserver4. this along with other article you can get complete flow.

Comment: [@user5049376's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43580090/18789859) may help you.